# P if and only if Q means, (P then q) AND (q then p)

Tags: logic

I was asked to state that the claim is true or false, I must give a prove to say it is true and counter example if it is false.

However I say it is True;This is a bi-conditional statement which mean p if and only if q. p implies q and q implies p which means it is true when both are true or both are false. This also means we combine two conditional statements together and the above claim sates that P if and only if q, means (p then q) AND (q then p) is putting or combining two conditional statements, which is true.

Is my reasoning correct or there is a law to prove that it is indeed true?

Comment: Your reasoning sounds correct to me.

Comment: There are indeed ways of manipulating symbols to go from $P \iff Q$ to $(P \implies Q) \land (Q \implies P)$, though this may turn out to be the definition of $\iff$.    There are also ways of manipulating symbols to go from $P \iff Q$ to $(P \land Q) \lor ((\lnot P) \land (\lnot Q))$.  Or you could use truth tables.  It all depends on what you start with, what manipulations you are allowed, and what you are aiming for.

Comment: You should take more care when writing. $P$ and $p$ are not the same thing, the same goes for $Q$ and $q$.

Comment: I'm not sure what your axioms,rules and definitions are. I'd say p=>q is only false if p is true and q is false so p=>q and q=>p is false when one is true and the other isn't and true if both are. But ... I don't know how p <=>q was defined if it wasn't so defined? By truth tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would express the proof as follows:

P if and only if Q means: P if Q **and** P only if Q.

By definition, P only if Q means: If not Q then not P.

So the original statement can be written as: P if Q **and** if not Q then not P.

P if Q means: If Q then P.

And by the contrapositive, if not Q then not P means: If P then Q.

So we are left with: Q then P **and** P then Q.